# Mule-XSLT transformation failing

Tags: xslt, transformation, mule

I am trying to transform an XML in Mule before calling my JDBC connector, however the transformation is failing with :

ERROR 2013-02-05 14:43:53,989 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)

This is even before I pass in the XML, here is the Mule Configuration:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint topic="${topic.logTopic}" connector-ref="jmsConnector" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:transaction action="NONE" timeout="${queue.transaction.timeout}" />
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>

    <mule-xml:xslt-transformer outputEncoding="UTF-8" ignoreBadInput="false" encoding="UTF-8">
        <mule-xml:xslt-text>
        <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
              xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:template match="ZLOIPRO1" >
          <table>
            <th><td>ZLOIPRO1</td></th>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
          </table>
        </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="data" >
          <xsl:attribute name="TABNAME">
            <xsl:value-of select="$TABNAM"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="data" >
         <xsl:attribute name="MANDT">
           <xsl:value-of select="$MANDT"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="data" >
        <xsl:attribute name="DOCNUM">
           <xsl:value-of select="$DOCNUM"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="data" >
        <xsl:attribute name="DOCREL">
          <xsl:value-of select="$DOCREL"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="data" >
        <xsl:attribute name="STATUS">
           <xsl:value-of select="$STATUS"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="data" >
        <xsl:attribute name="DIRECT">
          <xsl:value-of select="$DIRECT"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
       </xsl:template>

     </xsl:stylesheet>
   </mule-xml:xslt-text>
</mule-xml:xslt-transformer>


    <object-to-string-transformer/>

    <jdbc:xml-to-maps-transformer name="XMLToMaps"/>

    <jdbc:outbound-endpoint queryKey="insertion" connector-ref="insertionConnector">
```

Here is my XML:

```
<ZLOIPRO1>
  <IDOC BEGIN="1">
    <EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
      <TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
      <MANDT>300</MANDT>
      <DOCNUM>0000000000705856</DOCNUM>
      <DOCREL>640</DOCREL>
      <STATUS>30</STATUS>
      <DIRECT>1</DIRECT>
      <OUTMOD>2</OUTMOD>
      <EXPRSS />
      <TEST />
      <IDOCTYP>LOIPRO01</IDOCTYP>
      <CIMTYP>ZLOIPRO1</CIMTYP>
      <MESTYP>LOIPRO</MESTYP>
      <MESCOD />
      <MESFCT />
      <STD />
      <STDVRS />
      <STDMES />
      <SNDPOR>SAPR3P</SNDPOR>
      <SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT>
      <SNDPFC />
      <SNDPRN>R3PCLNT300</SNDPRN>
      <SNDSAD />
      <SNDLAD />
      <RCVPOR>5555</RCVPOR>
      <RCVPRT>LS</RCVPRT>
      <RCVPFC />
      <RCVPRN>SBCR3P300</RCVPRN>
      <RCVSAD />
      <RCVLAD />
      <CREDAT>20120512</CREDAT>
      <CRETIM>182139</CRETIM>
      <REFINT />
      <REFGRP />
      <REFMES />
      <ARCKEY />
      <SERIAL>20120512182139</SERIAL>
    </EDI_DC40>
    <E1AFKOL SEGMENT="1">
      <AUFNR>8390</AUFNR>
      <APROZ>0.00</APROZ>
      <AUART>ZP01</AUART>
      <AUFLD>20120605</AUFLD>
      <AUTYP>10</AUTYP>
      <BAUMNG>1.0000</BAUMNG>
      <BMEINS>EA</BMEINS>
      <BMENGE>1.0000</BMENGE>
      <CY_SEQNR>00000000000000</CY_SEQNR>
      <DISPO>401</DISPO>
      <FHORI>000</FHORI>
      <FREIZ>000</FREIZ>
      <FTRMI>00000000</FTRMI>
      <FTRMS>20120619</FTRMS>
      <GAMNG>1.0000</GAMNG>
      <GASMG>1.0000</GASMG>
      <GETRI>00000000</GETRI>
      <GEUZI>000000</GEUZI>
      <GLTRI>00000000</GLTRI>
      <GLTRP>20120619</GLTRP>
      <GLTRS>20120619</GLTRS>
      <GLUZP>000000</GLUZP>
      <GLUZS>000000</GLUZS>
      <GMEIN>EA</GMEIN>
      <GSTRI>00000000</GSTRI>
      <GSTRP>20120619</GSTRP>
      <GSTRS>20120619</GSTRS>
      <GSUZP>000000</GSUZP>
      <GSUZS>000000</GSUZS>
      <IASMG>0.000</IASMG>
      <IGMNG>0.000</IGMNG>
      <LODIV>0.000</LODIV>
      <MATNR>1007012-04-C</MATNR>
      <PLAUF>20120605</PLAUF>
      <PLNAL>1</PLNAL>
      <PLNME>EA</PLNME>
      <PLNNR>50000147</PLNNR>
      <PLNTY>N</PLNTY>
      <PLSVB>99999999.000</PLSVB>
      <PLSVN>1.000</PLSVN>
      <PSPEL>00000000</PSPEL>
      <RMNGA>0.000</RMNGA>
      <SBMNG>0.000</SBMNG>
      <SICHZ>000</SICHZ>
      <SLSBS>0.000</SLSBS>
      <SLSVN>0.000</SLSVN>
      <TERKZ>2</TERKZ>
      <VORGZ>000</VORGZ>
      <WERKS>3100</WERKS>
      <E1JSTKL SEGMENT="1">
        <STAT>E0006</STAT>
      </E1JSTKL>
      <E1JSTKL SEGMENT="1">
        <STAT>I0001</STAT>
      </E1JSTKL>
      <E1JSTKL SEGMENT="1">
        <STAT>I0016</STAT>
      </E1JSTKL>
      <E1JSTKL SEGMENT="1">
        <STAT>I0028</STAT>
      </E1JSTKL>
      <E1JSTKL SEGMENT="1">
        <STAT>I0115</STAT>
      </E1JSTKL>
      <E1JSTKL SEGMENT="1">
        <STAT>I0215</STAT>
      </E1JSTKL>
      <E1JSTKL SEGMENT="1">
        <STAT>I0291</STAT>
      </E1JSTKL>
      <E1JSTKL SEGMENT="1">
        <STAT>I0361</STAT>
      </E1JSTKL>
      <E1JSTKL SEGMENT="1">
        <STAT>I0420</STAT>
      </E1JSTKL>
      <E1AFFLL SEGMENT="1">
        <APLZL>00000001</APLZL>
        <AUSCHL>2</AUSCHL>
        <FLGAT>0</FLGAT>
        <PLNFL>0</PLNFL>
        <E1AFVOL SEGMENT="1">
          <VORNR>0010</VORNR>
          <ABRUE>0.000000000000000E+00</ABRUE>
          <ANZZL>0</ANZZL>
          <ARBEI>0.0</ARBEI>
          <ARBID>10000031</ARBID>
          <ARUZE>HUR</ARUZE>
          <AUFAK>0.000</AUFAK>
          <BEARZ>0.000000000000000E+00</BEARZ>
          <BEAZE>HUR</BEAZE>
          <BMSCH>1.000</BMSCH>
          <CY_SEQNRV>00000000000000</CY_SEQNRV>
          <DAUNO>0.0</DAUNO>
          <DAUMI>0.0</DAUMI>
          <FSAVD>20120619</FSAVD>
          <FSAVZ>000000</FSAVZ>
          <FSEDD>20120619</FSEDD>
          <FSEDZ>000000</FSEDZ>
          <FSELD>20120619</FSELD>
          <FSELZ>000000</FSELZ>
          <FSEVD>20120619</FSEVD>
          <FSEVZ>000000</FSEVZ>
          <FSSAD>20120619</FSSAD>
          <FSSAZ>000000</FSSAZ>
          <FSSBD>20120619</FSSBD>
          <FSSBZ>000000</FSSBZ>
          <FSSLD>20120619</FSSLD>
          <FSSLZ>000000</FSSLZ>
          <KALID>US</KALID>
          <LAR01>LAB02</LAR01>
          <LAR02>LAB01</LAR02>
          <LIEGZ>0.000000000000000E+00</LIEGZ>
          <LMNGA>0.000</LMNGA>
          <LTXA1>General Assembly</LTXA1>
          <MEINH>EA</MEINH>
          <MINWE>0.000</MINWE>
          <MGVRG>1.000</MGVRG>
          <PEINH>0</PEINH>
          <PREIS>0.00</PREIS>
          <PRZNT>0</PRZNT>
          <RMNGA>0.000</RMNGA>
          <RSTZE>HUR</RSTZE>
          <RUEST>0.000000000000000E+00</RUEST>
          <SPLIM>0</SPLIM>
          <SSAVD>20120619</SSAVD>
          <SSAVZ>000000</SSAVZ>
          <SSEDD>20120619</SSEDD>
          <SSEDZ>000000</SSEDZ>
          <SSELD>20120619</SSELD>
          <SSELZ>000000</SSELZ>
          <SSEVD>20120619</SSEVD>
          <SSEVZ>000000</SSEVZ>
          <SSSAD>20120619</SSSAD>
          <SSSAZ>000000</SSSAZ>
          <SSSBD>20120619</SSSBD>
          <SSSBZ>000000</SSSBZ>
          <SSSLD>20120619</SSSLD>
          <SSSLZ>000000</SSSLZ>
          <STEUS>PP03</STEUS>
          <TRANZ>0.000000000000000E+00</TRANZ>
          <USR04>0.000</USR04>
          <USR05>0.000</USR05>
          <VGE01>HUR</VGE01>
          <VGE02>HUR</VGE02>
          <VGW01>0.000</VGW01>
          <VGW02>5.000</VGW02>
          <VGW03>0.000</VGW03>
          <VGW04>0.000</VGW04>
          <VGW05>0.000</VGW05>
          <VGW06>0.000</VGW06>
          <VGWTS>Z001</VGWTS>
          <WARTZ>0.000000000000000E+00</WARTZ>
          <XMNGA>0.000</XMNGA>
          <ZLPRO>0.000</ZLPRO>
          <ZMINB>0.000</ZMINB>
          <ZMINU>0.000</ZMINU>
          <ZTMIN>0.000</ZTMIN>
          <ZWMIN>0.000</ZWMIN>
          <ZWNOR>0.000</ZWNOR>
          <ISAVD>00000000</ISAVD>
          <IEAVD>00000000</IEAVD>
          <ISDD>00000000</ISDD>
          <ISDZ>000000</ISDZ>
          <IEDD>00000000</IEDD>
          <IEDZ>000000</IEDZ>
          <ANZMA>0.00</ANZMA>
          <E1JSTVL SEGMENT="1">
            <STAT>I0001</STAT>
          </E1JSTVL>
        </E1AFVOL>
      </E1AFFLL>
      <E1AFPOL SEGMENT="1">
        <POSNR>0001</POSNR>
        <AMEIN>EA</AMEIN>
        <BMENG>0.000</BMENG>
        <KDAUF>1000021859</KDAUF>
        <KDEIN>0000</KDEIN>
        <KDPOS>000010</KDPOS>
        <MATNR>1007012-04-C</MATNR>
        <MEINS>EA</MEINS>
        <PLNUM>2718553</PLNUM>
        <PSAMG>0.000</PSAMG>
        <PSMNG>1.000</PSMNG>
        <UMREN>1</UMREN>
        <UMREZ>1</UMREZ>
        <WEBAZ>0</WEBAZ>
        <WEMNG>0.000</WEMNG>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>IZMT</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>IDCF</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>PPSR</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>PF01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>RFPO</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>TR01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>WT21</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>CH01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>AU01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>TP01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>PS01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X019</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X024</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>TM01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>AD02</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>SU01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>BT85</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>CC00</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>CN01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>DRLH</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>RENA</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>AU01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>BT85</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>CH01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>HP01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>PPSR</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>PS01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>RFPO</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>SC01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>SU01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>TM01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>TP01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>TR01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>WT21</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>SC01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>HP01</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X013</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X001</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X007</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X011</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X003</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X015</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X005</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
        <ZE1AFPO SEGMENT="1">
          <ZATWTB>X009</ZATWTB>
        </ZE1AFPO>
      </E1AFPOL>
    </E1AFKOL>
  </IDOC>
</ZLOIPRO1>
```

Any suggestions?

With Regards
Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with Mule, so take this with a grain of salt.

Your error message is from a SAX parser, so someone is trying to read some data they expect to be XML.  You say you get the error message even before you try to pass in the XML input, so we can guess that the problem is not in the input.  You provide a Mule configuration file -- configuration files often get read early, so an error in a configuration file seems like a plausible diagnosis.  And the configuration file you provide is not well formed XML:  it lacks a root element, it uses four namespace prefixes that are not bound to namespaces (jms, doc, mule-xml, and jdbc), and the jdbc:outbound-endpoint element at the end has no end-tag.  That input could easily elicit the error message you give, from a SAX parser.

So one plausible theory is that the problem is in your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

"Content is not allowed in prolog" usually means that something is wrong with your XML. In this case, the problem may be that your mule configuration file lacks of a root element, the mule tag. Here is an example in mule 3.2 (may not apply specifically for your needs since you use other components (jms, xsl etc..) and may use another version of the framework)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mxml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"
xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/3.2/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.1/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```